# Error al acceder a la propiedad de un objeto - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function __get() on string

Tags: php

Me parece el siguiente error al intentar acceder al valor de un atributo de un objeto. El código es el siguiente

Defino el objeto `usuario` utilizando los metodos magicos `__get`, `__set` y `__construct`  y la clase `tabla_usuario`(la cual es una especie de controlador)

```
<?php 
require_once "conexion/conexion.php";
class usuario{
    public $usuarioId;
    public $usuario;
    public $password;
    public $estado;
    public $ubicacion;
    public $tipoUsuario;
    public $nombre;
    public $avatar;
    public $movil;
    public $fc;

    function __construct(){
        return ;
    }

    public function __get($property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            return $this->$property;
        }
    }

    public function __set($property, $value) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}

class tabla_usuario{

    private $conexion;

    function __construct($conexion){
        $this->conexion = $conexion;
    }

    function insertar($usuario){
       
        $usuario = $usuario->usuario;
        $usuario = $usuario->__get("usuario");
        $password = $usuario->__get("password");
        $estado = $usuario->estado;
        $ubicacion = $usuario->__get("ubicacion");
        $tipoUsuario = $usuario->__get("tipoUsuario");
        $nombre = $usuario->__get("nombre");
        $avatar = $usuario->__get("avatar");
        $movil = $usuario->__get("movil");
        $fc = date("Y-m-d");
        $query = "INSERT INTO t_usuario (usuario,password,estado,ubicacion,tipoUsuario,nombre,avatar,movil,fc) 
        VALUES
        ($usuario,$password,$estado,$ubicacion,$tipoUsuario,$nombre,$avatar,$movil,$fc)";
        $resp = $this->conexion->nonQueryId($query);
        return $resp;
    }


    function crearObjUsuario($resultado =""){
        $usuario = new usuario;
        if($resultado == "") return $usuario;

        $usuario->__set("usuarioId",$resultado['usuarioId']);
        $usuario->__set("usuario",$resultado['usuario']);
        $usuario->__set("password",$resultado['password']);
        $usuario->__set("estado",$resultado['estado']);
        $usuario->__set("ubicacion",$resultado['ubicacion']);
        $usuario->__set("tipoUsuario",$resultado['tipoUsuario']);
        $usuario->__set("nombre",$resultado['nombre']);
        $usuario->__set("avatar",$resultado['avatar']);
        $usuario->__set("movil",$resultado['movil']);
        $usuario->__set("fc",$resultado['fc']);
        return $usaurio;
    }



    

}



?>
```

En otro documento creo la instancia del objeto  vacio y luego asigno los valores. con la funcion `__set`

```
        #Creo el objeto vacio ya que posteriormente asiganre los valores 
        $usuario = $tabla_usuario->crearObjUsuario();
        #asigno los valores a cada atributo del objeto
        $usuario->__set("password",$tabla_usuario->encriptarPassword($postBody->password));
        $usuario->__set("usuario",$postBody->usuario);
        $usuario->__set("nombre",$postBody->nombre);
        $usuario->__set("movil",$postBody->movil);
        $usuario->__set("codigoVerificacion",$tabla_usuario->codigoAleatorio());
        $usuario->__set("fc",date("Y-m-d"));
        $usuario->__set("tipoUsuario",1);
        $usuario->__set("estado",1);
       #Envio el objeto para ser guardado
        $id = $tabla_usuario->insertar($usuario);
```

Aquí es donde ocurre el error en la función `insertar`. El valor del primer atributo  `$usuario = $usuario->usuario;` lo asocia bien a la variable. pero los siguientes no.

Si cambio `$password = $usuario->__get("password");` a la posición del primer atributo accede bien  a su valor pero en los otros, no lo hace.

Lo extraño es que me deja imprimir con var_dump() todos los atributos sin problema.

```
    function insertar($usuario){
       
        $usuario = $usuario->usuario;
        #Qui es donde ocurre el error
        $usuario = $usuario->__get("usuario");
        $password = $usuario->__get("password");
        $estado = $usuario->estado;
        $ubicacion = $usuario->__get("ubicacion");
        $tipoUsuario = $usuario->__get("tipoUsuario");
        $nombre = $usuario->__get("nombre");
        $avatar = $usuario->__get("avatar");
        $movil = $usuario->__get("movil");
        $fc = date("Y-m-d");
        $query = "INSERT INTO t_usuario (usuario,password,estado,ubicacion,tipoUsuario,nombre,avatar,movil,fc) 
        VALUES
        ($usuario,$password,$estado,$ubicacion,$tipoUsuario,$nombre,$avatar,$movil,$fc)";
        $resp = $this->conexion->nonQueryId($query);
        return $resp;
    }
```

Estoy desarrollando en `PHP Version 7.4.14`

El error completo es el siguiente:

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function __get() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\github\Proyecto_Anuncios\models\usuario.model.php:44 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\github\Proyecto_Anuncios\rest\v1\register.php(53): tabla_usuario->insertar('w.aleman.hn@gma...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\github\Proyecto_Anuncios\rest\v1\index.php(13): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\github\Proyecto_Anuncios\models\usuario.model.php on line 44
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que creo que puede estar sucediendo en tu código es una colisión de variables en tu función insert(). La primera variable de la función `$usuario = $usuario->usuario;` se asocia bien, pero a partir de ahí la variable `$usuario` no sera el objeto de definido por `class usuario`, si no la propiedad que acabaste de declarar en con `$ usuario = $usuario->usuario;`. Básicamente cambiaste el valor de la variable `$usuario`.

Así que, que a partir de esa declaración, cuando pones `$usuario->__get("algo")` no se esta refiriendo al objeto, sino al string declarado. Por ello el error `Call to a member function __get() on string...`, ya que llamar a la función `__get()` con un string no tiene sentido.

La solucion que creo que puede funcionar seria el quitar esa primera declaracion de la variable `$usuario` en la funcion insert, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
function insertar($usuario){
       
        
        $usuario = $usuario->__get("usuario");
        $password = $usuario->__get("password");
        $estado = $usuario->estado;
        $ubicacion = $usuario->__get("ubicacion");
        $tipoUsuario = $usuario->__get("tipoUsuario");
        $nombre = $usuario->__get("nombre");
        $avatar = $usuario->__get("avatar");
        $movil = $usuario->__get("movil");
        $fc = date("Y-m-d");
        $query = "INSERT INTO t_usuario (usuario,password,estado,ubicacion,tipoUsuario,nombre,avatar,movil,fc) 
        VALUES
        ($usuario,$password,$estado,$ubicacion,$tipoUsuario,$nombre,$avatar,$movil,$fc)";
        $resp = $this->conexion->nonQueryId($query);
        return $resp;
    }
```

Espero esto te haya ayudado, un saludo.